# In R CMD INSTALL as a response to package installing through console

Tags: r, package, installation

I tried to install a package I got from github to R through the console:

```
install.packages("location_of_local_package.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

And R responded with this:

```
In R CMD INSTALL
```

I also tried using the package manager and changing type to source/win.binary/binary

Comment: In my experience, a `.zip` file indicates a "binary" package and a `.tar.gz` file indicates a "source" package, so there shouldn't have been need to go with `"source"` (but good on you for confirming). Unfortunately, this is not reproducible without seeing more details about the zip files. Perhaps you could include the output from `unzip -v location_of_local_package.zip` to confirm that the package looks like what it should? (Even that's not deterministic, though.)

Comment: To confirm, though ... are you certain that the package did not install? In the same session, does `packageVersion("local_package")` (whatever its name is) produce an error? If so, then I suspect that `install.packages(...)` had more on the console than just those four words; if so, please include the full output, warnings, errors, and all.

Comment: @r2evans unfortunately, it did not install. 
It had beenkind of mistakes and warnings when i tried win.binary or binary, but now only this output. Never seen it before

Comment: So you're saying that the console literally says just `In R CMD INSTALL` and promptly exits with nothing more said? Does it crash? If not, are you immediately interacting with the interpreter, so can enter commands once again? That isn't a programming mistake, that's a (not minor) [bug in R itself](https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html). In either case, this question is unfortunately not reproducible given what we know at the moment. If you want to `debugonce(install.packages)` and trace through where it fails, that would be incredibly useful, otherwise I think I cannot help much.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't crash and I can interact with console immediately.
The other person tried to install this package couldn't install it too, but I don't know what the error was, so maybe it is something wrong with the package. 
I'm new to R so I could have made some stupid mistakes, that also could be the problem. Anyway, thank you a lot.

Comment: I didn't realize somebody else tried with the same results. That is (to me) "strong" indication that the package is corrupt or invalid. If you put the output from `unzip -v ...` in your question, it might be clearer whether it looks like a package or something a friend clumped together. Whether binary or source, for example, the archive should have a single directory (named for the package) with, among other things, a `DESCRIPTION` file in that directory. If it doesn't look like that, then it is definitely not a proper package archive. Include the output and I might be able to help.

Comment: I don't know if the error the other person got is the same is mine.
I found the reason: this package came out two years ago and not available for R version 3.5.1
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That package was not compatible with the latest available version of R (3.5.1 currently).
Downgrade to R 3.3 solved the problem.